# How to extract substring from duplicate strings?

Tags: php, string, string-formatting

i have a specific problem .I am retrieving data in string format in PHP. I have to seperate the specific values from the string.My string looks like this

```
Barcode formatQR_CODEParsed Result TypeURIParsed Resulthttp://www.myurl.co.uk var ga.

Barcode formatQR_CODEParsed Result TypeTEXTParsed ResultMy Coat var ga.
```

As you can see from above two examples, The text after "Barcode formatQR_CODEParsed Result Type" and "Parsed Result" are changing. 
I have tried strstr function but it is not giving me desired output as the words "Parsed Result" is repeating twice.How can i extract ANY value /text that will come after these?How can I separate them?I would appreciate if someone could guide as i am new bee.
Thanks

Comment: Give us an example of what you want to input and what exactly you want to get. Also, you can have a look on function preg_match() http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: @Jar.Thanks Jar.How can i extract "URI" & "http://www.myurl.co.uk" from first string and how can i extract"TEXT" and "My Coat" from the second string given above??Thanks

Comment: Posted my answer for you using RegExp.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way is to parse this piece of HTML code with `SimpleXML` and get `<b>` children's values.

Answer (score 0):

just walk through the strings until you find the first difference. Shouldn't be a problem?

```
$str1 = "Hello World";
$str2 = "Hello Earth";

for($i=0; $<min(strlen($str1),strlen($str2)); $i++){
   if ($str1[$i] != $str2[$i]){
       echo "Difference starting at pos $i";
   }
}
```

or something like that. Then you can use substr to remove the equal part.

edit: IF your Strings always have the same Pattern, with values enclosed in `<b>` you can perfectly use a Regular-Expression to get the values.

Comment: @dognose.But how can retrieve the string between the first and last position?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution .We can extract strings this way:

```
<?
  $mycode='Barcode formatQR_CODEParsed Result TypeURIParsed Resulthttp://www.myurl.co.uk var ga';
   $needle = 'Parsed Result';
   $chunk=explode($needle,$mycode);                                                            

  $mychunky= $chunk[2];

        $needle = 'var ga';
 $result = substr($mychunky, 0, strpos($mychunky, $needle));

 print($result);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you. Also you can extend this idea futher and develop by your own needs.

```
$string = "Barcode formatQR_CODEParsed Result TypeURIParsed Resulthttp://www.myurl.co.uk var ga." ;
$matches = array() ;
$pattern = "/Type([A-Z]+)Parsed Result([^>]+) var ga./" ;

preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches) ; // Returns boolean, but we need matches.
```

Then get the occurences:

```
$matches[0] ; // The whole occurence
$matches[1] ; // Type - "([A-Z]+)"
$matches[2] ; // Result - "([^>]+)"
```

So you use elements with indeces 1 and 2 as Type and Result respectively. Hope it can help.